# Implied volatility of Below intrinsic value Heston prices for deep calibraiton

Tags: implied-volatility, heston, calibration, neural-networks

I am trying to generate implied volatility surfaces for European call in the Heston model. I get below intrinsic values for deep ITM, so about 2% of my surface has below intrinsic prices, which doesn't allow me to calculate its implied volatility. I need these surfaces to train a CNN for deep calibration. Is setting the implied volatility of below intrinsic value options '0' the answer? How can I avoid getting below intrinsic value prices (I guess it's due to numerical instability in the quantlib integration ?). Thank you

Comment: A few scattered thoughts. 1. a below intrinsic price is obviously wrong, so any vol that comes out of it must be wrong -- likely you don't want to calibrate a model on a wrong vol!. 2. In general, implied vols of deep ITM/OTM options are less accurate (the vega is very low) so you might want to consider whether you really want to calibrate on deep ITM/OTM in general.